# What options exist under OSX for embedding a browser window?

Tags: macos

I have an app that I'm porting to OSX. On Windows it uses an ugly but functional windows webbrowser control.  On Linux I use gtk webkit. What options do I have available on OSX?

Ideally I'd like to work with something already built in rather than have to download 100MB extra for an app that is only 1MB.  The browser functionality is simply to provide login functionality that can't easily be mimicked with dialog boxes.

Comment: I'm not an OSX expert but did you look for Webkit?

Comment: Ok, it seems there is something called Webkit Framework.   I'll try that.

Comment: [This](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app/) might be interesting.